# Angular material tabs custom HTML

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am having issues with angular material tabs, i need to remove tabs on other side of html, not to wrap in entire html.
Here is example with default tabs that is working ok

```
<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="1">
            <md-content class="md-padding">1</md-content>
           </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="2">
            <md-content class="md-padding">2</md-content>
        </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

But i need to have something like this

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
    <md-tab label="1">
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="2">
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>


<div class="main">
    <md-content class="md-padding">1</md-content>
    <md-content class="md-padding">2</md-content>
</div>
```

I know there is option on

```
**md-on-select="" md-on-deselect=""**
```

But how to make it in my case?

Comment: Why do you need this can you explain? Can you provide a user story?

Comment: Because i need some custom element in html because of design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/BLwEEb?editors=1010)

Link the `md-selected` attribute of the `md-tabs` with `ng-switch` on the main `div`.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="vm.selectedIndex">
      <md-tab label="1">
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="2">
      </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>

  <div class="main" ng-switch="vm.selectedIndex">
      <md-content class="md-padding" ng-switch-when="0">1</md-content>
      <md-content class="md-padding" ng-switch-when="1">2</md-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```